# The Entrance to the Catacombs

Tags: riddle, story

This puzzle is a prequel to: [The Catacombs of Cryptos, The Final Path](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31828/the-catacombs-of-cryptos)

---

We have finally found the lost Catacombs of Dias Cryptos, a man known for his love of hiding his belongings, in hard-to-obtain fashion.  The seven of us have searched, for months, to find this place, but at last, we have arrived.  Perhaps there is hope for us, yet.

> The building before us is almost monumental in its design, but its structure appears a mark of simplicity.  Before us lies a wall of a metal that I am not familiar with, and a quite solid looking door, with no apparent handle.
>
> Cid approaches the door, and attempts to open it.  A panel that we had not noticed, on the wall, quickly slides away, causing him to step back in surprise. It reveals a screen with the following text:

```
I might stand on a line, so you know who I am  
I'm in beehives, and snowflakes, most of the time  

If you are highly skilled, you may find me in paired hats
Elsewhere, my five friends and I affect your wealth  

Some could travel the gridiron to find me  
Or you may simply gaze upon the wings of a seraph  

I can also be seen in my non-divisive friends  
But only the sexy ones, relatively speaking  

Do you know who I am?  Please.  Do tell.  
If so, continue this path, if you can find the courage
```

> We all spend some time, discussing the problem, among the group, but no one can agree on what it could be.
>
> Ramot starts to get impatient...again.  "Why don't we just smash this door down?  Cryptos is long since dead, and we are getting *nowhere*, guys!  What's he gonna do?"
>
> Ramot stalks over to the door and begins banging, kicking, and doing just about anything else he can think of to get through the door.  The door, however, seems disinterested.  "This is stupid, man!" he says, in disgust.
>
> The panel on the wall now changes, for a moment. "Incorrect response," it displays.  Suddenly, there is silence as Ramot is gone, a pile of ash in his place.  Maia's jaw drops as she hides her face in her hands, tears poking out from around them, while the rest of us just stare, aghast, at the small pile.  I don't think any of us even saw what just happened, exactly.  The panel once again displays the riddle, for us to solve.
>
> Clearly, Ramot was wrong.  Cryptos will still have his way with deciding who gets into his catacombs.  The remaining five, and myself, must find the solution to this inane riddle so we can get inside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is...

> SIX.

I might stand on a line, so you know who I am

> Sixes are sometimes marked with underlines to distinguish them from nines.

I'm in beehives, and snowflakes, most of the time

> Beehives and snowflakes usually have sixfold symmetry.

If you are highly skilled, you may find me in paired hats

> A "hat trick" is three consecutive wins: double 3 and you get 6.

Elsewhere, my five friends and I affect your wealth

> My five friends, and I, make up a die, commonly used for gambling.

Some could travel the gridiron to find me

> A touchdown is six points (thanks, @q_a)

Or you may simply gaze upon the wings of a seraph

> seraphs have six wings.

I can also be seen in my non-divisive friends
But only the sexy ones, relatively speaking

> Sexy primes are two primes with a difference of six.

Comment: This was Maia's idea!  We couldn't figure out how to make the clues fit, but this seems, at least mostly, reasonable.  We'll try it, thanks!